# android - mediaplayer not sending range headers

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-streaming

I have an android app which uses the MediaPlayer. I want to stream wav PCM audio to the app, so I am using MediaPlayer. My problem is that the MediaPlayer does not send the Range header so the server returns the whole file instead of small parts of it. How can I make the media player send the range header?

Comment: I could do that by sticking a local proxy between the remote server and `MediaPlayer`. That was before `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor` existed. There's also [ExoPlayer](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) that may be of some help.

Comment: Why should a proxy help? won't the MediaPlayer still expect the whole file to be downloaded before starting playback?
I am looking into exoplayer as we speak. seems to support it.

Comment: The proxy helped because I had full control to what content the MediaPlayer would see. I would make range requests behind the scenes and just hand off content to the MediaPlayer as a continuous stream.

Comment: OK, but I don't think I can use a proxy. What's the relevance of MediaCodec and MediaExtractor?

Comment: It worked well, but I emphasize that it was a workaround for not having MediaCodec. It was for an embedded system and we had no choice but to use the version of Android that was installed.